# java.lang.Throwable: Unable to determine gradle tasks to execute

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I'm a beginner with android and I have a problem: I cannot run emulator, nothing happens. The IDE shows me a FATAL ERROR:

java.lang.Throwable: Unable to determine gradle tasks to execute

I tried some solutions:
I restarted Android Studio and rebuild the project and also did Invalidate Caches / Restart but none didn't worked.

```
java.lang.Throwable: Unable to determine gradle tasks to execute
    at com.intellij.openapi.diagnostic.Logger.error(Logger.java:137)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.run.DefaultGradleBuilder.build(DefaultGradleBuilder.java:42)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.run.MakeBeforeRunTaskProvider.doExecuteTask(MakeBeforeRunTaskProvider.java:360)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.run.MakeBeforeRunTaskProvider.executeTask(MakeBeforeRunTaskProvider.java:268)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.run.MakeBeforeRunTaskProvider.executeTask(MakeBeforeRunTaskProvider.java:122)
    at com.intellij.execution.impl.ExecutionManagerImpl.lambda$compileAndRun$0(ExecutionManagerImpl.java:317)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$1.run(ApplicationImpl.java:314)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 1):

It is due to gradle is not synced in your project. go file there is sync project with gradle file then you can able to run your project